# update $scope with asynchonous function before $state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to update $scope variable with asynchronous function run,
I run this function with ng-click. Here is my function:

```
$scope.linkData = (id) => {
    myService.getData(id)
        .then((data) => {
          $scope.data = data.data.response;
          $timeout(() => {
            $scope.$applyAsync($scope.data);
            $state.go('/');
          });
        })
        .catch((data) => {
            console.log("error")
        });
  }
```

But there is no this variable in scope, please help, what I missed?

Updated myservice:

```
   'use strict';
    app.factory('myService', ($http) => {
        let myService = {
            //get Data
            getData : (data) => {
                return $http.get('api/profile?token=' + data)
            }   
        };
        return myService;
    });
```

Comment: Are you using babel?

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Comment: @frosty, yes I using babel, and there is no any error, function run, but not update scope

Comment: @frosty, when $state loads view, there is no data variable in scope

Comment: In the `myService.getData` call, are there any non-angular async calls? If any of the code in `getData` call does an async call outside of angular, then you will need to call a `$rootScope.$applyAsync()` in order to have angular update your DOM with the new data.

Comment: If you put a console.log to log "hello" after the line: `$scope.data = data.data.response`, does it fire?

Comment: @frosty, inside function I can get the value, but outside I get undefined

Comment: I need to see the `getData` call.

Comment: @frosty, updated

Comment: Instead of setting your scope to `data.data.response`, what if you just set it to `data.data`? I am guessing that `data.data.response` is undefined, and that `data.data` has a value you are looking for.

Comment: @frosty `data.data.response` has value I need, the problem is, asynchronous run, this why I'm trying update scope after `getData()` run

Comment: It will be undefined outside your function until your promise has resolved and updated the data

Comment: @frosty, I run `$scope.linkData()` function on ng-click, so it's run asychronous, and variable is undefined outside function, and I trying to apply it to scope

Comment: @cnorthfield, I also tried to use it with `$q.defer()` promise, but result the same

Comment: When the UI-Router executes `$state.go`, it destroys the old $scope and creates a fresh new one. To carry data to a different state, either store it in a service or add a property to the parameter object. `$state.go("/", { data: $scope.data })`. For more information see [UI-Router API Reference - $state.go](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/state.stateservice.html#go).